# Numpy.loadtxt using skiprows keyword with function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to use the skiprows to miss the comments from a data files. Each comment line begins with the symbol #. Although, I do not know the total number of lines for every data file. The docs https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html do not give more details. From the code below,

```
import numpy as np

data = np.loadtxt(filname, skiprows=5)
```

How can I skip all lines which begin with the # - symbol?

Comment: Have you tried it?  It should be skipping the comment lines automatically (unless you've done something with the `comments` parameter).

Comment: @hpaulj I have not tried it! I use the symbol # to emphasize the comment lines. Although, it is not necessary.

Comment: You linked to the documentation.  If you read it, you'll see that the default value of the `comments` argument is `'#'`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Yes it is. I did not watch out exactly the doc. Stupid question!